# How to get records from a table with two column have same value?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table with name agent_payment with schema.

```
Schema::create('agent_payment', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('agent_id');
        $table->integer('created_by');
        $table->integer('rid')->nullable()->comment('Only For Admin Reservation');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->string('paid_amount');
        $table->string('paid_by')->nullable();
        $table->string('received_by')->nullable();
        $table->enum('type',['cash','cheque']);
        $table->string('bank_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('cheque_num')->nullable();
        $table->string('deposited_to')->nullable();
        $table->string('account_num')->nullable();
        $table->string('slip')->nullable();
        $table->integer('verified')->default(0)->comment('Verified 1 Unverified 0');
        $table->integer('status_change')->default(0);
        $table->string('reject_message')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have model for this table AgentPayment.

Now, I am trying to get records with same value in two column.

Simply I need records with

status_change = 0 and verified = 0

or

status_change = 1 and verified = 1

It's easy to get any one of above like:

```
$payments = AgentPayment::where('status_change',1)->where('verified',1)->get();
```

But how to get both of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to achieve a couple of grouped wheres then you can do it using closures like this:

```
AgentPayment::where(function($query) {
    return $query->where('status_change', 1)->where('verified', 1);
})->orWhere(function($query) {
    return $query->where('status_change', 0)->where('verified', 0);
})->get();
```

This should result in query that looks like:

```
select * from agent_payment where (status_change = 1 AND verified = 1) OR (status_change = 0 AND verified = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should give you your answer:

```
$payments = AgentPayment::where(['status_change', 1],['verified', 1])->orWhere(['verified',0], ['status_change', 0])->get();
```